# How to get a visa for an internship in Bali

Tags: visas, singapore, indonesia

I am a French student about to do a 2-month internship in Bali. On my way to Indonesia, I will have a stopover in Singapore. While there, I would like to get visa to enter Indonesia for my internship.

Is that possible and, if it is, how and where can I do it? I'm leaving France on 04/18....

Comment: I'm not sure it matters but paid or unpaid internship?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you leaving France on 04/18? Is it April 2018 or 18th April (which would mean you left already)?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, to make it clearer. If I have misunderstood, I apologize, and you call roll back the changes, or make your own edits.